# Format date according to the device configuration, but force YYYY instead of YY

Tags: java, android

I want to format correctly according to the device configuration a date, but I want to force YYYY instead of YY. My current code is the following:

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.
                DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
String fDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

For example, if dateFormat is `dd/mm/yy` it must become `dd/mm/yyyy`, if dateFormat is `yy/mm/dd` it must become `yyyy/mm/dd` and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically change the formatting for the device or just your app. As date formatting is related to locale/language see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2900023/295004

Comment: @MorrisonChang just for my app

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code, it will give you the date in your format:

```
DateFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").print(new LocalDate())
```

Comment: This is not a question for this answer: "according to the device configuration".

Comment: Sorry my bad, can't delete through the android app but will when I get back on my PC :)